# Почему таймер на останавливается?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

В компоненте хочу реализовать таймер, по истечении которого надо сделать запрос. Пошуршал по гугглу и стеку  примеры таймеров, прикрутил свое. Получилось следующее:

```
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            secondsRemaining: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        let {secondsRemaining} = prevState;

        if (secondsRemaining === 0) {
            // REQUEST
        } else {
            this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
        }

    }


    handleItemClick = () => {
        this.setState({
            activeItem: itemIndex,
            secondsRemaining : data.time && data.time
        });

    };

    tick = () => {
        this.setState({secondsRemaining: this.state.secondsRemaining - 1});
        if (this.state.secondsRemaining <= 0) {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
    };
}
```

По клику на айтем меню задействуется хендлер `handleItemClick`, который сетит в стейт `secondsRemaining` в секундах(например 60 секунд). Далее срабатывает `didUpdate` и условие таково, что когда `secondsRemaining` будет равно нулю, то надо выполнить запрос, если нет, ты с интервалом в 1 секунду методом `SetInterval` мы отсчитываем время. Это работает,но не совсем так как надо. Он доходит до 0 и продолжает отнимать -1,-2,-3 и так о бесконечности. Какой-то косяк в моей логике,но я не пойму какой. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: у вас в `handleItemClick` откуда `itemIndex` берется?

Comment: да `data.time` что за переменная?

Comment: itemIndex это переменная не связанная с таймером ее можно пропустить. data.time это анные которые приходят с апи там число, например 60

Comment: сколько раз вызывается `componentDidUpdate`? Вполне возможно, что при запуске следующего таймера, id предыдущего просто затирается и его уже не остановить.

Comment: @Grundy до клика по компоненте запускается и после клика,когда считает

Comment: @Iga неверно, вы в тике вызываете `setState`, что запускает апдейт, после которого вызовется `componentDidUpdate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    let {secondsRemaining} = prevState;

    if (secondsRemaining === 0) {
        // REQUEST
    } else {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 1000);
    }

}
```

Метод `componentDidUpdate` вызывается каждый раз, как у вас срабатывает апдейт компонента, даже когда вы уже запустили таймер, то есть после каждого вызова таймера, вызывается этот метод, где проверяется условие, которое снова срабатывает ( таймер обновляется, правда старый таймер никуда не исчезает )

Поэтому в итоге у вас куча таймеров в памяти = утечка памяти

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      secondsRemaining: 100
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    let { secondsRemaining } = prevState;

    if (secondsRemaining === 0) {
      // REQUEST
    } else if (!this.interval) { // только если еще нет таймера
      this.interval = setInterval(this.tick, 10);
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    // обязательно при анмаунте удаляем таймер
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.interval = undefined;
  }

  handleItemClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      secondsRemaining: 100
    });
  };

  tick = () => {
    this.setState({ secondsRemaining: this.state.secondsRemaining - 1 });
    if (this.state.secondsRemaining <= 0) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
      this.interval = undefined;
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.state.secondsRemaining}</div>
        <button onClick={this.handleItemClick}>click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, rootElement);
```

Comment: работает все кроме clearInterval как в процессе он выставляется =29 так и остается ,не сбрасывается

Comment: @Iga что значит _работает все кроме clearInterval_?

Comment: значит,что таймер стартует, происходит отсчет. когда secondsRemaining = 0, должен сработать clearInterval, который как я понимаю обнулит this.interval. Вот это и не происходит. досчитывает до 0 и все.

Comment: @Igo `clearInterval` не обнуляет интервал, а удаляет его, то есть интервал перестает вызываться, это стандартное поведение `clearInterval`

Comment: удаляет, то есть this.interval станет вновь undefined?

Comment: @Iga в данном случае нужно в ручную удалить интервал, поправил ответ

Comment: @Iga `clearInterval` останавливает таймер, но там все равно еще хранится число ( id таймера )

Comment: теперь понял. работает. большое спасибо за помощь